# procedure give me garbage data in some fields

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird1.5

I have that code:

```
string pathToSave = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
            string file = pathToSave + "\\" + "produkty_" + lang + ".csv";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
           // sw.WriteLine("id;Akt. 1/0;nazwa;kateg.;cena netto;stawka pod;cen suger.;wyprz.;o;d;d;nr kat.;dostępne od:;prod.;ilość;opis skróc;opis;konserwacja");

            OdbcCommand Qry = new OdbcCommand(query, con);
            OdbcDataReader dataReader = Qry.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                //SELECT p.COUNTER, p.AKT, p.NAZWA, p.KATEGORIA, p.CENA_NETTO, p.STAWKA_VAT, 
                //p.CENA_SUGEROWANA, p.WYPRZ, p.O, p.COSTAM, p.D1, p.D2, p.NR_KAT, 
                //p.DOSTEPNE_OD, p.COSTAM2, p.PROD, p.COSTAM3, p.COSTAM4, p.COSTAM5, p.ILOSC, p.OPIS_SKRO, p.COMPOS, p.CONSERV

                string counter         = String.Empty;
                string AKT             = String.Empty;
                string NAZWA           = String.Empty;
                string KATEGORIA       = String.Empty;
                string CENA_NETTO      = String.Empty;
                string STAWKA_VAT      = String.Empty;
                string CENA_SUGEROWANA = String.Empty;
                string WYPRZ           = String.Empty;
                string COSTAM          = String.Empty;
                string D1              = String.Empty;
                string D2              = String.Empty;
                string NR_KAT          = String.Empty;
                string DOSTEPNE_OD     = String.Empty;
                string COSTAM2         = String.Empty;
                string PROD            = String.Empty;
                string COSTAM3         = String.Empty;
                string COSTAM4         = String.Empty;
                string COSTAM5         = String.Empty;
                string ILOSC           = String.Empty;
                string OPIS_SKRO       = String.Empty;
                string COMPOS          = String.Empty;
                string CONSERV         = String.Empty;

                counter = dataReader["COUNTER"].ToString();
                AKT = dataReader["AKT"].ToString();
                NAZWA = dataReader["NAZWA"].ToString();
                KATEGORIA = dataReader["KATEGORIA"].ToString();
                CENA_NETTO = dataReader["CENA_NETTO"].ToString();
                STAWKA_VAT = dataReader["STAWKA_VAT"].ToString();
                CENA_SUGEROWANA = dataReader["CENA_SUGEROWANA"].ToString();
                WYPRZ = dataReader["WYPRZ"].ToString();
                COSTAM = dataReader["COSTAM"].ToString();
                D1 = dataReader["D1"].ToString();
                D2 = dataReader["D2"].ToString();
                NR_KAT = dataReader["NR_KAT"].ToString();
                DOSTEPNE_OD = dataReader["DOSTEPNE_OD"].ToString();
                COSTAM2 = dataReader["COSTAM2"].ToString();
                PROD = dataReader["PROD"].ToString();
                COSTAM3 = dataReader["COSTAM3"].ToString();
                COSTAM4 = dataReader["COSTAM4"].ToString();
                COSTAM5 = dataReader["COSTAM5"].ToString();
                ILOSC = dataReader["ILOSC"].ToString();
                OPIS_SKRO = dataReader["OPIS_SKRO"].ToString();
                COMPOS = dataReader["COMPOS"].ToString();
                CONSERV = dataReader["CONSERV"].ToString();
                //if (COMPOS.Contains(@"\"))
                //{
                //    COMPOS = "";
                //}
                StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"c:\kan\fileOuput1.txt", true);
                wr.WriteLine(
                counter + ";" +
                AKT + ";" +
                NAZWA + ";" +
                KATEGORIA + ";" +
                CENA_NETTO + ";" +
                STAWKA_VAT + ";" +
                CENA_SUGEROWANA + ";" +
                WYPRZ + ";" +
                COSTAM + ";" +
                D1 + ";" +
                D2 + ";" +
                NR_KAT + ";" +
                DOSTEPNE_OD + ";" +
                COSTAM2 + ";" +
                PROD + ";" +
                COSTAM3 + ";" +
                COSTAM4 + ";" +
                COSTAM5 + ";" +
                ILOSC + ";" +
                OPIS_SKRO + ";" +
                COMPOS + ";" +
               CONSERV + ";"
               );
                wr.Close();
```

And when I save it to csv file in COMPOS and CONSERV I get some garbage data, looks like combination of some fields etc :/ Do You have any idea why it's happens? And this take place for some rows, not always ...

Comment: Why do you initialize all those local variables to empty strings and *then* read from the dataReader? Why not do the two together? Just a thought around readability... Also you're missing *lots* of `using` statements for resource cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things you can try:

- Try checking these rows in the DB. Are they valid?
- Do they have any special characters that are messing up the fields?
- Debug the datareader object itself to check if the data was properly fetched, if not check your query.

Comment: In db these fields are empty.It's varchar fields. It's looks like I have that error only when I use Visual Studio 2010, cause in earlier version it's ok o.O

Comment: @netmajor: do you try with newer version of Firebird ?

Comment: unfortunately company I worked don't want to use newer version of FB :/ They stay at 1.5. I am sure that in 2.0 it's should resolved...